# trying to pass the value (which is extracted from json path extractor) to the next http request

Tags: json, path, jmeter, extractor

I have extracted 10 values from a Json path extractor, naming device_1,device_2,device_3 to device_10. I am able to see these 10 values in debug sampler and now i want to pass on these value to the next http request one by one (may be by using a loop) but i am not able to find any way where i can pass all these 10 values one by one to next http request. As of now i am sending only 1st value as ${device_1} in the http request but i want 10 different users to access all 10 values one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) is something you're looking for.

Configure it like:

[image]

and use `${device}` in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler which is inside the [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller).

[image]

The HTTP Request will be executed as many times as there are matches generated by the JSON Extractor.

[image]

The similar concept is described in [Using Regular Expressions in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-jmeter) article

Comment: That worked magically at first attempt only....thank u....u are the best.